# How to increase the thickness and change colors of the edges in a mesh?

Tags: graphics3d, mesh

Consider 10 random points as

```
pts =  RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10, 3}];
```

The edges of the polyhedron formed by these points can be visualized as

```
HighlightMesh[DelaunayMesh[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10, 3}]], 
 Style[2, Opacity[0.]]]
```

However, The edges are thin. I want to change the thickness of the edges and the colors as well.

**Edit 1**

In my approach and the answer provided by @Szabolcs, all the edges along with some inner planes are visible while I need only the outer edges and no surface or plane.

How can I do this?

**Edit 2**

I got it.

```
Show[HighlightMesh[
  ConvexHullMesh[pts], {Style[1, {Black}], 
   Style[2, Opacity[0.]]}]]
```

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, these options don't work directly in `DelaunayMesh` in 3D (they do for 2D meshes), but they do work in a `MeshRegion` applied afterwards.

```
m = DelaunayMesh[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {10, 3}]]

MeshRegion[m, 
 MeshCellStyle -> {2 -> None, 
   1 -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[3], Red]}]
```

[image]

Comment: I don't mind how it is done. I am happy with the result. Thanks.

Comment: However, I have found two problems with this solution. Firstly, it shows all the edges (which was there in my approach as well) while I need only the outer edges and not the diagonals. Secondly, I find that some of the surfaces formed by these points are still not transparent.

Comment: @Majis What are "diagonals"?

Comment: @Majis Regarding inner edges, that was not in your question. If I understand what you are sayig then you want the ConvexHullMesh, not the DelaunayMesh.

Comment: The diagonals are the edges which do not lie on the surface of the convex hull formed by these points.